# Trouble with single quotes in Select expression

Tags: c#

The code is pretty simple:

```
string expression = "User = '" + user.UserName + "'";
int selectionCount = Data.Select(expression).Count();
```

It works fine until user.UserName doesn't contain single quote '. For example, if user.UserName equal something like "gul'mirka" then app crashes. How to fix this?

Actually user.UserName can contain anything, even only numbers (7548375982) or mathematical equations (1 + x = 4).

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried String.Parse ?

Comment: You can use query parameters for this

Comment: What is `Data`?

Comment: What if you escape the single quote, like in SQL?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks. I really do hope there are better answers these days.

Comment: @PatrickHofman However the duplicate contains also the correct answer (doubling the quotes)

Comment: Pointed the duplicate to another question with a clearer accepted answer.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, Data is a DataTable.

Comment: @splash27: Okay. Then the duplicate will do.

Answer (score -1):

Could you convert your query to a lambda statement?

```
var result = Data.Where(x => x.User == user.UserName).ToList().Count();
```

Comment: If Data is an untyped DataTable, I don't believe that will work.

Comment: Not far to be right. Just add AsEnumerable().

Answer (score -1):

Escape the single quotes:

```
string expression = "User = \'" + user.UserName + "\'";
int selectionCount = Data.Select(expression).Count();
```

Comment: Doesn't help. The problem is the quotes inside the `userName`, not the outer ones.